# Div acting like panel

Tags: html

I have a div with grooved border.
I want it to look like this panel: http://www.devmanuals.com/images/images1/444Panel1.gif

The panel on the image has title "User registration".
How to make my div has a title like the panel?

Comment: post what you have tried

Answer (score 3):

That is called a **fieldset**, and it is a basic HTML tag.

```
  <fieldset>
    <legend>User Registration</legend>
    User name: <input type="text" /><br />
    Password: <input type="text" /><br />
  </fieldset>
```

I cringe at giving you a link to [this site](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_fieldset.asp), but it does have the ability for you to try out your HTML right there.

Answer (score 1):

Try a "fieldset":

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>caption goes here</legend>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do some styling on the fieldset.

Stylesheet.css

```
fieldset.panel
{
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 200px;
}
fieldset.panel input[type=text]
{
    width: 170px;
}
```

Usage

```
<fieldset class="panel">
    <legend>User Registration</legend>
    User name:<br/><input type="text"/><br/>
    Email-id:<br/><input type="text"/><br/>
    Password:<br/><input type="text"/><br/>
    Confirm password:<br/><input type="text"/><br/>
    <br/>
    <input type ="submit" value="Register"/>
</fieldset>
```

Basically it's using a fieldset but with some basic styling, the css class `panel` will make the border 1px solid black and the inputs are all going to be 170px width, since the css style will only be applied to the `input`s which `type` is `text` and being inside a `fieldset` whose `class` attribute is `panel`, translated to css like this: `fieldset.panel input[type=text]`.